# Live wood coffee table

Tags: finishing, wood

Going to use a prestain, then perhaps golden oak to even out the dark and light variations.   Question what do I protect it with against red wine etc.   I already have a red wine ring .    I have used varothane but wondering about boiled linseed, tung oil etc.    I have never used these oils tho. Worried that wood would crack?  Oil better?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. OK first thing <screech of brakes> why are you intending to use pre-stain? What species are you dealing with?

Comment: Second thing, StackExchange is not like a regular threaded forum as the introductory tour should have made clear. In addition to each Question ideally being about just one thing there's also a no-duplicates rule and all three elements you touch on are *amply* covered in previous Q&As here so please do a search. When/if to use pre-stain or "wood conditioner" products is addressed and you'll find a shortlist of the species it *might* be beneficial for (and this IS a short list, most woods *do not* need it) along with the caveats if you do go ahead with it. Oil versus varnish also well covered.

Comment: A simple search for "pre stain" found the proposed duplicate. Also, taking the [tour] (as noted by Graphus) will help you learn your way around here.

Comment: Welcome Nadine.  As mentioned in other comments your question appears to be a duplicate of several others.  I am going to close this, but if you find that there are parts of previous Q/A posts that are not addressed, please come back and ask that specific question.  To learn more about how this stie works take the [tour](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour).